# Junit Testing in Netbeans with Maven - What is wrong with my setup?

Tags: java, junit, netbeans

UPDATE: Solution & Lessons

- Corrected naming convention to be detected by Maven/JUnit: IngredientTest, not Ingredient_Test.
- Deleted runner class (not required for tests).  Struggled with how exactly to run tests to see results (without any main method).
- Solution: in netbeans, ran the test file from original class (Ingredient), NOT the test class (IngredientTest).  Right-click in body of original class (Ingredient), click 'Test file'.  Upon completion, an output and and test result window should open.

[netbeansSnapSolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t35g.png)

Thanks Chrylis, it appears I was mixing JUnit 4 & 5.

https://learn.vogella.com/courses/details/java-software-testing

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/

---

What I'm trying to do: write and run JUnit on existing classes in netbeans.

What's wrong

- @Before in Ingredient_Test: "Cannot find symbol"
- imports in Ingredient_TestRunner: "Package <> does not exist."

Environment

- Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.4
- Java: 16; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 16+36-2231
- Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 16+36-2231
- Project built with Maven as default, though I haven't modified the Maven XML file in any manner, saving that as the next tutorial item after unit testing.

Background:  I wrote my own quick ad hoc test classes (mixed in with src files), meaning to do proper Junit testing "later".  I'm several classes in, and I should have started with proper testing!  Now I'm in the process of rewriting ad hoc test classes properly.

[NetbeansSnap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhdQz.png)

Thanks in advance.

---

```
package com.riverrat.recipebook;

public class Ingredient{

    String name;
    String amount;
    String unit;
    String form;
    
    // do stuff
}
```

---

```
package com.riverrat.recipebook;

import com.riverrat.recipebook.Ingredient;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class Ingredient_Test {
    
    @Before
    public void buildIngredients(){
        Ingredient beans = new Ingredient("beans");
        Ingredient onions = new Ingredient("onions", "2", "cups", "chopped coarsley");
        Ingredient water = new Ingredient("water", "3", "oz");
        Ingredient bacon = new Ingredient("bacon", "", "slab");
    }
 
    @Test
    public void testNames(){
        assertEquals("beans", beans.name);
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.riverrat.recipebook;
import org.JUnit.runner.JUnitCore;      
import org.JUnit.runner.Result;     
import org.JUnit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class Ingredient_TestRunner {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Result result = JUnitCore.runclasses(IngredientTest);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailure()){
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Result " + result.wasSuccessful());
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Does it work when you run maven from the command line?

Comment: For starters, package names are case-sensitive. There's also a chance you're mixing JUnit 5 and JUnit 4.